# How to set up environment variable for all tests in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, junit

Setting up environment variables for hundreds of tests get old very quick. Is there a way to declare an environmental variable globally in Eclipse?

Can this be done in Eclipse? Can this be done outside of Eclipse?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the only way to do it is to enable "`Run all tests in the selected project ..`" and set `Environment` variables once there.

If you want to run a single test, and that test requires an environment variable set, it looks like you need to set that environment variable as part of that tests's settings.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In windows use the "start" command to spawn eclipse from command line with defined variables  (linux has similar functionality)

Make file starteclipse.cmd

================================

```
SET VAR1=SOMEVALUE
SET VAR2=SOMEVALUE
start d:\eclipse\eclipse.exe
```

================================

From command line go to the dir with starteclipse.cmd file and run it.

This will spawn eclipse with proper environment settings.

Comment: this is the ONLY answer that I could find on the web

Answer (score 0):

I also find it frustrating having to set env vars one by one.
If you own the code and have a chance to change it, you'd be better off using a System property instead, which can be passed as VMArgs -Dprop=val.

You can set VM args in a global level - Preferences | Java | Installed JREs, and Plugin Development | Target platform.

Even if you can't change the code, most well civilised java libs support properties as well if not more than env vars- so it's worth double checking.
(of course it's not an option for external processes).